# Vim RegEx: Match until blank line

Tags: regex, vim, newline

I'm trying to write a RegEx that will match any line that contains ".wpd", and then match all lines after that until it reaches a blank line (including the blank line).

This is what I've tried:

```
/\v^.*.wpd\_.\{-}^\s*$
```

However, the non-greedy operator `\{-}` after the "all characters including new lines" character class `\{-}` doesn't seem to work. If I use

```
/\v^.*.wpd\_.*
```

that will match the next line containing ".wpd" and then *all* lines after that. However, as soon as I change the `*` to `\{-}`, it doesn't match anything at all.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below. You were quite close, only needed to use the `anwhere` variations of the start-of-line and end-of-line characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the atom `^` (same for `$`) *inside* the regexp, it has its special meaning only at the front (back); elsewhere, it's taken as the literal char. Use `\n` to match a newline inside the regexp, as shown by perreal's answer.

Comment: Alternatively, use the *anywhere* equivalents of the anchors. Therefore, use `\_^` and `\_$`. Therefore the expression could be simplified to `\v^.*.wpd\_.{-}\_^\s*\_$`

Answer (score 8):

This one seems to work:

```
/\v^.*\.wpd\_.{-}\n\s*\n
```

Comment: Awsesome, thanks. I accepted Ingo's answer because he explained why mine didn't work, but it was a tough call, and I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?s)[^\n\r]*\.wpd(.*?)\n{2}
```

(?s) - Turn on 'dot matches line breaks' to search across lines

[^\n\r]* - Starting at the beginning of a line, match anything that's not a line break

.wpd - Match '.wpd'

(.*?) - Match anything, non-greedily, including line breaks ( because we turned on (?s) previously )

\n{2} - ... until you find two newlines in a row, which would be a blank line

:)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a large supporting comment to @perreal's answer above as well as my own version of that answer which I find more intuitive.

Let's dissect the following regexp based on http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic

```
/\v^.*\.wpd\_.{-}\n\s*\n
```

1. `\v` (lowercase v): This is the 'very magic' operator which
       signifies that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
   '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.
   Therefore, characters like `*` , `^`, `$` need not be escaped in the pattern but for `_` to have special meaning (such as modifying the behaviour of `.` to match newline), it needs to be escaped. Hence with `\v` set, you need `\_` for the latter to have special meaning. 
   To truly appreciate how much `very magic` simplifies the expression, compare it with the same expression using the `very NOmagic`(uppercase `\V`):
    `/\V\^\.\*.wpd\_\.\{-}\n\s\*\n` (very nomagic) vs 
    `/\v^.*\.wpd\_.{-}\n\s*\n` (very magic)
2. `^.*\.wpd`: Greedily match anything (`.*`) from the beginning of a line (`^`) till `.wpd`
3. `\_.` : Matches a single character, which can be
       *any* character including the newline. 
    Note that with `\v` set, the pattern must have escaped underscore as noted above.
4. `{-}` : Is the non-greedy equivalent of `*` quantifier. So, where `.*BLAH` matches the most possible characters till BLAH, `.{-}BLAH` will match the least possible. To see this in action, take a look at this (in this case, I had to use `?` instead of `{-}` since that regex is PCRE) : 
   [image]
5. `\n\s*\n`: Matches a blank line which may contain one or more spaces or tabs
6. `\_.{-}\n\s*\n`: combines the above two and means 
    Match the least possible number of characters including newline (`\_.`) until a blank line (`\n\s*\n`)
7. `\v^.*\.wpd\_.{-}\n\s*\n`: Finally putting it altogether, 
    set the *very magic* operator (possibly to allow simplifying the pattern by not needing to escape anything except an `_` for special meaning), search for any line which contains `.wpd` and match until the closest blank line.

---

#### My version using variants of end-of-line start-of-line characters

The only modification is to the expression used to signify a blank line. I find it useful to define a blank line in terms of the start-of-line ('^') and end-of-line ('$') characters, however as-is, they cannot be used anywhere in a regexp except the beginning and the end respectively.

For the above use-case, there are variants which can be used anywhere in a regex, namely: '_^' and `\_$` respectively. Therefore the blank line expression can be written as `\_^\s*\_$` instead of `\n\s*\n`, thus making the complete expression:

`\v^.*.wpd\_.{-}\_^\s*\_$`

This perhaps is closer to answering the OP's question about why they were unable to use the start-of-line character in their expression.

Phew!